# Importance of baseline testing over SLA's

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

Why we are comparing Performance test results with base line if we already have SLA's?

How they will be related-
For example:

- Transaction response time in main test is 3 seconds
- SLA for same transaction is 5 second
- Baseline for that transaction was 2 seconds

How to compare these?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about methodologies in testing. This may be a suitable question for sqa.stackexchange.com but please check their help pages before asking there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If time is over SLA - you have a **critical production issue** that need to be address.

If time is over baseline - your server suffer from performance degradation and it need to be analyse,but in lesser importance

Read more in [testingperformance](http://www.testingperformance.org/performance-articles/service-level-agreements):

> Any user action where the response time seems to be higher than expected can be traced, monitored and checked to determine if their are any inefficiencies.
>
> - As the workload is increased, the performance tester can look to see how the response times of transactions deviate from the baseline as the workload increases.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer - are you the recipient of an SLA (as in your system uses an external system with an SLA) or do you have to guarantee an SLA?

Typically people use "baseline" to mean the application as it is now, running in typical conditions and under typical load.

Typically, a response time SLA includes upper limits on load, or some kind of commercial ladder - guaranteeing a response time for unlimited traffic is often impossible without additional financial resources.

If your first performance test suggests that the actual response time is higher than baseline, it suggests that either you disagree about "typical" conditions, or that you've exceeded those typical conditions, or that the application's performance has deteriorated since the baseline was established. That's important information.

In general terms, response times and load do not have a linear relationship - if response time is 1 second with 100 users, it's usually not 10 seconds with 1000 users. Instead, response time tends to rise very slowly with load until you hit a bottleneck, at which point it rises very steeply.

I typically use performance testing to explore those bottlenecks, so I can decide how they fit with my desired performance characteristics, and work out how to move that bottleneck further away.

It's also worth noting that most systems have multiple bottlenecks, and the slowest element determines the overall performance characteristics. So even if you have an SLA for 5 second transactions in one part of your architecture, there may be other parts that are slower (or reach their bottleneck sooner).

So, why do you compare your load tests with base lines, even if you have an SLA?

- Make sure that the baseline is still valid.
- Make sure you understand the overall performance characteristics and can exceed the SLA in other parts of the system.
- Verify you can reach the SLA